# Does Couchbase replicate keys across datacenters in any particular order?

Tags: couchbase

I need keys to be transferred between datacenters roughly in order, either in the order they are inserted or in the order of the keys (since I can make sure the keys are inserted in lexiographical order).

Since updated documents are pushed to a replication queue, it seems like they are transferred roughly in the same order they were inserted/updated. Is this correct? Is this something I can rely on for now, even if it's not explicitly documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no, they aren't sent in any particular order", and you shouldn't design your system to expect an order.

The slightly longer answer is each vBucket (aka shard) has a replication stream, so in a typical deployment there will be 1024 streams from the source cluster to the destination cluster. Mutations within a stream will be sent in order (and indeed they have sequence numbers) but different streams are independent and hence mutations which belong to different vBuckets may be replicated "out of order".

However the vBucket which a document belongs to is automatically managed by Couchbase and is essentially opaque, so you should't rely on particular documents being assigned to particular vBuckets.

Answer (score -1):

Couchbase is a mult-master system (AP). Therefore, there can be no such thing as a "global" order for your keys.  In fact, any database that has transactions (even on a single node) can appear to create records "out of order".

Sure, you could design your entire system around the usecase of "we'll never add more Couch nodes", but that's a bad idea. Either change your design, or change your database to one that works more like you want.

Comment: I ment if the order of the sync from each datacenter was roughly ordered. Just a replication from DC1 to DC2, where only DC2 doesn't write to that bucket. Of course different datacenters will not be synced.

Comment: Couchbase isn't an AP system, nor is it multi-master - a given document has a single master location (bucket) in a given cluster. Therefore it's CP in a single cluster. Cross-datacenter replication does change this, but it's incorrect to describe Couchbase as AP in the general case.